# How to set up Google tag Manager configuration in ASP NET Core razor pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, asp.net

I am very new to ASP NET Core razor pages. I have a requirement to set up Google Tag Manager in ASP NET Core razor pages. Usually in the ASP.Net solution we use Google Analytic's `tag.js` script in page load. In angular we usually set up in `app.module.ts` and `app.component.ts`.

But, I am to set up GTM tracking code and id in ASP NET Core razor pages.

After set up, I need to send triggering conditions to GTM (like on button click send a event trigger to GTM so that it will in turn call the Google Analytics set up tag). Is there any helper class or plugins which I can use for the same? Or in which file like `Startup.cs`, I can use the GTM configuration set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used Razor Pages, but it looks like it allows you to have an HTML template, i.e. HTML that is reused site-wide or on groups of pages.

So you would just need to get your tracking code and put it into the `<head>` section of all pages. This post addresses how to run Javascript tags in a similar fashion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311783/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-include-javascript-file-in-the-head-tag

Once Tag Manager is set up, you can run GA from a GTM tag that fires on all pages.

Comment: Thank you for the reply !

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if theres anything else I can help with here.